# Button onClickView is not working while implementing OnClickListener

Tags: android

I created 5 classes.One class is main activity and rest are intent activities...I implemented OnClickListener interface directly to class.While running android project button event is not working.Source code is given below.

```
package com.sooraj.cbsroot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeMainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnBus, btnAbout, btnContact, btnAdmin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_main);
        btnBus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBus);
        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        btnAdmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdmin);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBus) {
            Intent intentBus = new Intent(HomeMainActivity.this,
                    BusDetails.class);
            startActivity(intentBus);
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAbout) {
            Intent intentAbout = new Intent(HomeMainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intentAbout);
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnContact) {
            Intent intentContact = new Intent(HomeMainActivity.this,
                    Contact.class);
            startActivity(intentContact);
        }

        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnAdmin) {
            Intent intentAdmin = new Intent(HomeMainActivity.this,
                    AdminLogin.class);
            startActivity(intentAdmin);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Register onClickListner first for all the buttons. Then click events will work.

Answer (score 4):

Please use this

```
    btnBus.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnContact.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAdmin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

in OnCreate Method.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to register the `OnClickListener`

```
   btnBus.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you have to do this operation for every `Button` instance